# SVM Predict Levels not matching between test and training data

Tags: r, svm

I'm trying to predict a binary classification problem dealing with recommending films.

I've got a training data set of 50 rows (movies) and 6 columns (5 movie attributes and a consensus on the film).

I then have a test data set of 20 films with the same columns.

I then run

```
pred<-predict(svm_model, test)
```

and receive

Error in predict.svm(svm_model, test) : test data does not match model !.

From similar posts, it seems that the error is because the levels don't match between the training and test datasets. This is true and I've proved it by comparing `str(test)` and `str(train)`. However, both datasets come from randomly selected films and will always have different levels for their categorical attributes. Doing

```
levels(test$Attr1) <- levels(train$Attr1)
```

changes the actual column data in test, thus rendering the predictor incorrect. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

The first half dozen rows of my training set are in the following link.
https://justpaste.it/1ifsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, assuming Attr1 is a character:

1. Create a levels attribute with the unique values from attribute1 from both test and train.
2. Create a factor on train and test attribute1 with all the levels found in point 1.

   ```
   levels <- unique(c(train$Attr1, test$Attr1))
   test$Attr1  <- factor(test$Attr1, levels=levels)
   train$Attr1 <- factor(train$Attr1, levels=levels)
   ```

If you do not want factos, add `as.integer` to part of the code and you will get numbers instaed of factors. That is sometimes handier in models like xgboost and saves on one hot encoding.

`as.integer(factor(test$Attr1, levels=levels))`

Comment: My attributes are characters. Executing your code then results in test$Attr1 and train$Attr1 being "<NA>" for all values. Also, I noticed that running unique returns all integers instead of characters (not sure if that's meant to be). Any insights?

Comment: @user2402616  What are the values of `unique(train$attr1)`? Do you have numbers defined as chars? Otherwise, put dput(head(train, 6)) in your question. That would help a bit better with understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: The values for all my attributes are strings. In this case, they're strings of people's names. Also, your code did resolve my error in that I'm now able to successfully use the predict function. However the result is just "factor(0)" with the levels of my label column being printed out. I've attached the results of the dput command to my question.

Comment: The way you are reading your data transforms every column into factors. Try reading the data with the option `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. The code above with the as.integer option I use in kaggle competitions and doesn't fail me.

Comment: Removing stringsAsFactors and then using your code did it. Thanks